# Web scraping: how to get scraper implementation from text link?

Tags: java, screen-scraping, factory

I'm building a java web media-scraping application for extracting content from a variety of popular websites: youtube, facebook, rapidshare, and so on.

The application will include a search capability to find content urls, but should also allow the user to paste a url into the application if they already where the media is. [Youtube Downloader](http://youtubedownload.altervista.org/) already does this for a variety of video sites.

When the program is supplied with a URL, it decides which kind of scraper to use to get the content; for example, a youtube watch link returns a YoutubeScraper, a Facebook fanpage link returns a FacebookScraper and so on.

Should I use the factory pattern to do this?

My idea is that the factory has one public method. It takes a String argument representing a link, and returns a suitable implementation of the Scraper interface. I guess the Factory would hold a list of Scraper implementations, and would match the link against each Scraper until it finds a suitable one. If there is no suitable one, it throws an Exception instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea. You most likely want a singleton with a create(URL url) method. I would recommend you use TDD to do this to get your requirements clearer in your mind.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree that passing a URL argument would be better than passing a String.

Answer (score 0):

A factory returning the stuff will be fine. To generalize the attempt, I recommend to use a map for holding implementations, i.e.:

```
Map<String, Class<Scraper>> scrapers = new HashMap<String, Scraper>();
scraper.put("facebook.com", FacebookScraper.class);
...
```

Later you can check the url with the keys of the map and instantiate the right class for that content.

Comment: Thanks, I think that a map from urls to scrapers would be a good way to go about it. But as Thorbjørn said, the exact type should be Map<URL, Class<Scraper>> instead.